# Paths and permissions in Windows

Tags: python, windows

I wrote a fast and easy hack to walk thru directories (in stepmania song dir), find conf-files and name the directory the conf-files are in to a certain name found in the conf-file. This works great on my linux box. But not at my wives Windows XP-box running as an admin. I get permission-error. What's wrong? Here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from __future__ import with_statement

import os
import re
import sys

def renamer(in_path):
    for (path, dirs, files) in os.walk(in_path):
        exts = ['.sm', '.dwi'] # Only search files with this suffix
        conf_files = [] 

        # Create list with conf-files
        for ext in exts:
            conf_files.extend([file for file in files if file.lower().endswith(ext)])

        # Search for conf-files in directory 
        for conf_file in conf_files:
            try:
                with open(os.path.join(path, conf_file)) as f:
                    match = re.search('TITLE:\s?(.*);', f.read()) # Search for whatever follows "TITLE:"
                    new_dir_name = match.group(1) # The new dir-name is whatever the TITLE states in conf-file
                    os.rename(path, os.path.join(path, '..', new_dir_name)) 
            except IndexError:
                print 'No conf-file in', path

if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1].replace('\\', '/') # Windowsify the path
    renamer(path)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows can't rename a path that has an open file. It should work if you move the `os.rename` call out of the `with` block so that the file is closed. However, you're repeating this for multiple files in the same path, and the directory name in `path` will no longer exist after you've renamed it. Also, `os.walk` can't traverse subdirectories after you've renamed the parent directory.

I would check the config files while walking the tree and append `(path, new_path)` tuples to a list. Then I'd rename the directories in reverse order.

Also, `match` might be `None`, in which case trying to access `match.group` will raise an `AttributeError`. And Windows system calls seem to handle mixed separators fine in case you want to skip the 'Windowsify' step. To clean up a path for printing/logging, `os.path.normpath` consistently uses `os.path.sep` as well as resolving '.' and '..' in a path.

Comment: Oh, That makes perfect sense. I'll start coding right away! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Are you forgetting to put a drive letter on your path, like `C:\`?  Print out the value of `path` in the very bottom of your code and see if it gives you something you could directly paste into the Windows file explorer.

Comment: It's seems right. A "print path" just before renamer(path) returns c:/traningspass (which is right as far as i understand)